# How to retrieve the package and class info for an argument function in Scala?

Tags: scala, function, class, reflection, package

Is there a way to get the full package and class info/names for a function passed as an argument? Imagine the following case:

```
package mypackage

class MyClass {
  def func(a: Int): Int = {
    a * a
  }

  def getPackageInfo(f: Int => Int): String = {
    // return package and class name of f
  }
}
```

In that case invoking `getPackageInfo(func)` somewhere in `MyClass` should return something like `mypackage.MyClass.func`.

I am aware that `f` might be an anonymous function that does not belong to a class, which could be handled by an extra check.

I also don't mind changing the signature of `getPackageInfo`, as long as it can accept methods and return their package and class info.

Answer (score 1):

A normal function can't do it, because even if you write `getPackageInfo(func)` the compiler expands it to an anonymous function: by definition it's the same as `getPackageInfo(func _)` which is the same as `getPackageInfo(x => func(x))`. The information you want is just not stored in `f`, so there is no way to get it out.

But you can do it using a macro. https://github.com/dwickern/scala-nameof should be a useful starting point to modify: it'll give you `func` instead of `mypackage.MyClass.func`.